# SSRS occasional broken image for database image

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report with 2 subreports, but the last subreport is showing images from the database. The images show up as a small thumbnail, to be clicked to open up in a new page a larger version of the image. It is the same file only different proportions depending on which report is being executed.

The issue I'm seeing is that I will occasionally get the following: an image and a black 'x' image returned when I drill down to the details of the report.

[image: Image1]

Is this performance related? Are images too resource intensive? There can be hundreds of images, but in the example above there were less than a dozen small images.

Comment: Have you already verified that the images exist on disk and aren't corrupt in some way?

Comment: Yes I have. The images all exist and I have permission to view them.